# Kotlin: expecting menber declaration when it seems I have already done

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, kotlin-coroutines

I found few questions with same error message but, as far I can see, I have declared it properly.

Here is the whole code in Kotlin:

```
package com.mybank.service

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher
import com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase
import java.util.Arrays
import org.bson.Document

class test {


    //MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    var mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:q@localhost:27017")
    var database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
    var collection: MongoCollection<Document> = database.getCollection("mycollection")

    var doc: Document = Document("name", "MongoDB")
            .append("type", "database")
            .append("count", 1)
            .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
            .append("info", Document("x", 203).append("y", 102))


    //publisher decalred and initialized
    var publisher: Publisher<InsertOneResult> = collection.insertOne(doc)

    publisher *** why publisher isn't initialized yet???
```

It is working in java that way

```
imports ommited, same as above
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        //MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:q@localhost:27017");
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycollection");

        Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));


        Publisher<InsertOneResult> publisher = collection.insertOne(doc);

        publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber<InsertOneResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
                s.request(1);  // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final InsertOneResult result) {
                System.out.println("Inserted: " + result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }
        });

        //all examples
        collection.countDocuments()
                .subscribe(new SubscriberHelpers.PrintSubscriber<Long>("total # of documents after inserting "
                        + " is: %s"));

        collection.find(eq("name", "MongoDB")).first().subscribe(new SubscriberHelpers.PrintDocumentSubscriber());

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

}
```

The error message:

[image: IntelliJ]

I am not coding to Android and here is the build.gradle althought I think it is not relevant

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id "application"
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
}

version "0.2"
group "account-control"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")

    //Kafka
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")

    //vertx
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-mysql-client")
    //implementation("io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-vertx-mysql-client")
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin:3.9.4'

    //mongodb
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.1.1")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")

    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")

    testImplementation enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0")
    testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5")
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "account-control.Application"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allOpen {
    annotation("io.micronaut.aop.Around")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}
//compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateProto)

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

*** edited

```
package com.mybank.service

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher
import com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase
import java.util.Arrays
import org.bson.Document
import javax.inject.Singleton

class test {


    //MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    var mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:q@localhost:27017")
    var database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
    var collection: MongoCollection<Document> = database.getCollection("mycollection")

    var doc: Document = Document("name", "MongoDB")
            .append("type", "database")
            .append("count", 1)
            .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
            .append("info", Document("x", 203).append("y", 102))


    //publisher decalred and initialized
    var publisher: Publisher<InsertOneResult> = collection.insertOne(doc)
}
```

then in other class

```
@Singleton
class TransactionService(){

    @Inject
    lateinit var test: test

    fun postDebitTransaction(debit: String) : String{

        test.publisher.subscribe(
                object x: Subscriber<InsertOneResult> {
                    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                        s.request(1) // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
                    }

                    override fun onNext(result: InsertOneResult) {
                        println("Inserted: $result")
                    }

                    override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
                        println("Failed")
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        println("Completed")
                    }
                })

        return "posted"
    }
}
```

And I am getting

Type mismatch.
Required:
Subscriber<in InsertOneResult!>!

I am quite sure I am doing some silly error in Kotlin

Comment: what is the return type of `collection.insertOne(doc)` ?

Comment: going deeper by control + click I see Publisher<InsertOneResult> insertOne(TDocument var1); so I understand the return type is Publisher. And control+clicking in Publisher I see

public interface Publisher<T> {

    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> s);
}

Comment: Hmm... https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't tell you the member is not initialized, it's telling you that you are not allowed to call functions in the class body without them being part of a member declaration.

e.g.

```
class Foo {
    // not allowed
    3.toString()
}

class Bar {
    // prefectly fine
    val three = 3.toString()
}
```

Java has the same behavior.
Why your java sample works, is because your code is inside the `main` method and not the class body.

Comment: Thanks. I din't get your point. If I understood correctly the same you have done with val three = 3.toString() I have done with var publisher: Publisher<InsertOneResult> = collection.insertOne(doc)

Comment: Yes, but you are not allowed to call `publisher.subscribe` in the class body

Comment: I inject this class in other Singleton class:  @Inject
    lateinit var test: test and then I can at least test.publisher.subscribe. But then I get Type mismatch.
Required:
Subscriber<in InsertOneResult!>!. I will add the whole code above

Comment: Kindly, can you run your eyes on code above and tell me what I am doing wrong in Kotlin?

Comment: @JimC the problem with your code is that you haven't declared `main()` function in your Kotlin code